# Take active cells value and copy to another cell. Excel VBA

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, loopback

I am putting together a list to loop through in Excel.

I want to loop down column A starting at A2, and copy the value from the active cell to D2 (always D2)

This is what I have so far:

```
Sub Test2()

    Range("A2").Select

    Do Until IsEmpty(ActiveCell)

    'Take value from active Cell and copy to D2
    MsgBox ("Continue")

    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select

    Loop
End Sub
```

I tried replacing `'Take value from active Cell and copy to D2` with `Range("D2).value = ActiveCell` but this did not work.

Any suggestions.

So to recap. D2 will equal A2, I will get message box, press continue, then D2 will equal A3, and so on...

I have also tried:

```
Sub TestLoop()

    Dim Selected As Variant
    Selected = Selection.Value

    Range("A2").Select

    Do Until IsEmpty(ActiveCell)
    Range("D2").Value = Selected
    MsgBox ("Continue")

    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select

    Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: Side note: In general, it is better to [avoid using select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba) in your code

Answer (score 1):

Just figured I'd add a simple version of your answer without the `.select`

```
Sub TestLoop()
Dim r As Range
Set r = Range("A2")
Do Until IsEmpty(r)
    Range("D2").Value = r '.Value
    MsgBox ("Continue")
    Set r = r.Offset(1)
Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: thanks I wouldn't have known where to start with removing the select

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this.

I was placing the variable outside of the loop, I think.

```
Sub TestLoop()

    Range("A2").Select

    Do Until IsEmpty(ActiveCell)
    Dim Selected As Variant
    Selected = ActiveCell.Value

    Range("D2").Value = Selected
    MsgBox ("Continue")

    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select

    Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: If you want to clean up your code consider 1) moving your `Dim` statement to be the next line after your `Sub` statement. It may not be an issue for VBA, but it would cause errors with other languages. 2) or just get rid of `selected` and alter your line to ` Range("D2").Value = ActiveCell.Value`. Also consider @cybernetic.nomad suggestion.

Comment: @gns100 I tried but it errored out on me, it seems the dim has to be in the loop, will try active cell.value tho, I’m quite newish to vba so any pointers are very welcome